# How to stop save -data if the data is saved within today for a user

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

```
class RequestPop(models.Model):

    request_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=False,null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    available_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.user,self.request_pop)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user:
            old_obj = RequestPop.objects.filter(user=self.user).filter(created_at = datetime.today).last()
            if not old_obj:
                super(RequestPop, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But my code is not working. How to stop save data if data already saved within today.

Comment: `created_at ` is a `DateTimeField` field but you filter with a date. Which then most probably uses another hour-minute then the object in the DB.

Comment: Try filtering with : `...lter(created_at__day = datetime.to...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
class RequestPop(models.Model):
    request_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    available_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.user, self.request_pop)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user:
            now = timezone.datetime.now()
            today_midnight = timezone.datetime(day=now.day, month=now.month, year=now.year)
            old_obj = RequestPop.objects.filter(user=self.user).filter(created_at__gte=today_midnight).last()
            if not old_obj:
                super(RequestPop, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you @Josewails. It Does work!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do like this:

```
RequestPop.objects.filter(user=self.user).filter(created_at__lte = datetime.today()).last()
```